# Include layout returns blank space

Tags: android, layout, include

I'm using include in one of my layouts and it just returns a blank space. Not sure what is going on.

Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/title1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/section">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titletext1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="List"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:textColor="#555555"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="13dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/recent1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/list"/>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/recent2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/list"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:background="@drawable/list_bg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        style="@style/list_button">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="Text1"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5.0dp"
                android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textColor="#666666"
                android:text="Text2"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: set `LinearLayout` with id `title1` orientation to `vertical`, if not set, the orientation is `horizontal`, and your `relativelayout`'s `width` is `fill_parent`, which means, other layout is place right to your `relativelayout` and hence nothing shown.

Comment: nicely done sir, it's always the little things GEES. Alright post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your main `LinearLayout`'s `orientation` to `Vertical`. By default, the `orientation` of a `LinearLayout` is `Horizontal`.

the first child of your `LinearLayout`, which is `RelativeLayout` with `layout_width="fill_parent"` (btw `"fill_parent"` is now deprecated, use `"match_parent"` instead of it), take all the screen width, hence other `Views` won't get shown.

Comment: didn't know about the fill_parent, thanks for that info as well

Comment: hey you wouldn't happen to know how to get my `list.xml` relativeLayout1 background to work right? it's an .xml that changes colors on `android:state_pressed`...

Comment: what is the problem? you need a `<item >` and `<item android:state_pressed >` on your drawable. `<item >` for normal appearance and `state_pressed` for state when pressed.

Comment: never mind, got it. `android:clickable="true"` in the relativeLayout attributes.